# Node and Socket.io ... prevent outside clients from connecting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, socket.io

Hi I am facing an issue with my web application which has a chat room.From looking into it I think its related to setting `origins` option ? But I am in doubt and would appreciate any help to lead me in the right direction. To keep it short, what I found is that a user who is not directly on my webpage can easily connect to the chat port through simply adding the `connect(ip:port)` function in their client side scripts. What security mechanism is needed to prevent this kind of access. Also I am not using `node.js` to actually serve the webpages, but rather laravel. Node mainly implements the chat functionality and transfers messages to and from the clients as well as storing them in memory.

I hope my question is clear enough, if not let me know

Comment: i am having the exact same issue, looks like some other chat site is able to connect to my chat server. How did u restrict this from happening? my server is on node js socket io.

Comment: Hey @Faizan as pointed out in the below answer the solution would be to introduce a validation system similar to any traditional API service. For instance the node server can authenticate a fresh connection with username/password then reply with a uniquely generated token. From there on wards the client can send that token as "proof of identity" and the node server would validate the token prior to performing any subsequent actions. Now keep in mind I have given a very high level and simplified solution just to help you get the idea. There are pros and cons to each method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser-based webSocket connections (e.g. connections initiated from Javascript in a browser) can be limited to "same-origin" with the right server-side settings so that only web pages from your own site can connect.  This is because browsers cooperate and announce the legitimate origin that the connection is coming from so the server can decide if the incoming connection is legit or not.

Non-browser-based webSocket connections, e.g. connections made from another server or some script outside of a browser cannot be limited to same origin (because no trusted agent sets the origin from which they come).  If you want to control those types of connections, you will need some sort of authentication scheme or API key or something like that or give up on regulating it and control whatever you need to control in other ways (rate limiting, user logins, detect non-people connections, etc...).

A webSocket connection is really no different from an ajax connection in this regard.  If a web page can use it, then it's pretty much open to the whole internet unless you implement some sort of authentication scheme.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer, the problems makes more sense now. So it really comes down to having a control measure in place on the server so every attempted socket connection is verified ? My next obvious question is what measure best suits my situation. And what is more commonly used in these situations. Also what do you mean by 'give up on regulating it'  ?

Comment: @MrSSS16 - "Give up on regulating" means you don't worry about who connects (that is kind of a hard problem when browser JS is allowed to connect because it is wide open for every one to see what it's doing), but rather you worry about what they do when they're connected so they don't do things that a client shouldn't (like automate responses too quickly or flood too many commands or whatever might cause grief in your system).  You can require a user login or you can piggy back on existing user auth on your web site and then if you detect a mal-behaving user, you can ban that user account.

Comment: ohh I see ... but does that not pose any serious threats. I'm probably wrong but if they can connect even if I regulate it with verification/validation. Does the mere fact that they have connected impose any issues ? For example if my server has got a function that emits messages. And they emit that through their own code...would a measure to see if the socket emitting is actually authenticated be adequate ?

Comment: @MrSSS16 - we'd really need to understand the specifics of what you need to protect your server or system from.  Answers in the abstract aren't really possible.  A rouge connection listening to messages the server sends is no big deal - that's just like another connected browser.  The impact of messages a rouge connection might send on its own depends entirely upon the situation, but is no different in analyzing or protecting than a rouge Ajax request is to your web server - exact same issue, exact same exposure.